# Certificate error when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server

When trying to connect to SQL Server, I get the following error:

> (node:9364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 10.120.6.11:1433 - self signed certificate

When I use SQL Server 2014, it works normally.

Note: You need a vpn to connect.

Code:

```js
const config = {
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT, 10),
    server: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_Database,
    stream: false,
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true,
        encrypt: true,
        enableArithAbort: true,
        trustServerCertificate: false,
    
    },
}

sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
    if (pool.connecting) {
        console.log('Connecting to the database...')
    }
    if (pool.connected) {
        console.log('Connected to SQL Server')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I had the same error message (`Failed to connect to xxx:1433 - self signed certificate`). Then I used `trustServerCertificate: true`. This fixed the error for me.

Comment: For those using react: https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/

Comment: This was it for me. Ugh... hours of searching, this helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

I encountered the same problem on my project. I manage to solve the problem by adding `trustServerCertificate: true`

Example (NestJS and TypeORM usage):

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mssql',
  host: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
  username: 'sa',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'DB',
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
  extra: {
    trustServerCertificate: true,
  }
}),
```

Answer (score 14):

What works with me, with the full script:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var sql = require("mssql");
    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'P@ssw0rd',
        server: 'WIN-N4J1057LVFV', 
        database: 'WIN-PAK_ALL',
        synchronize: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
    };
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from cardHistory', function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
        });
    });
});
var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a connection string:

```
        sql.connect('Server=localhost,1433;Database=database;User Id=username;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;');
```

Answer (score 1):

This error i have encounter when trying to connect sqlserver from a Node application.
**I manage to solve the problem by adding trustServerCertificate: true.
Please add the connection string as follow.**

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = {
    server: 'Deb',
    database: 'ProjectDB',
    port:1433,
    user: 'sa',
    password: '123',
    trustServerCertificate:true,
    options: {
        cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
            minVersion: 'TLSv1',
            trustServerCertificate: true,
        }
    }   
  };
  
const connectDatabase = () => {
  
// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
        console.log('Connected to SQL Server');
    }

});  
    }

module.exports = connectDatabase;
```

Answer (score 1):

trustServerCertificate: **true**. This fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const config = {
    user: 'your_username',
    password: 'your_password',
    server: 'your_server',
    database: 'your_database',
    options: {
        encrypt: false 
    }
};
```

Comment: This seems to be a confirmation / thank you to existing answers, because it duplicates `const config`.

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.